# Exclude certain files from distutils install command

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I want to ensure that certain files in a Python package do not get installed when the user types:

```
python setup.py install
```

Specifically, under certain conditions, there can be `__pycache__` directories that end up in the `build` directory, and if the user then runs `install`, the `__pycache__` directories get installed too, and this causes issues down the line. The solution is probably to create a custom install command with:

```
class CustomInstall(DistutilsInstall):
    # code here
```

but after browsing around in the distutils code, I can't figure out how to edit the list of files that gets installed. Does anyone have any suggestions? I could make `CustomInstall` delete all the files I don't want, but I would like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Having to write a custom command sounds like a lot of work for this.  Alternate ideas:

- Use different build directories for Python 3.2 (which creates __pycache__) and 2.7 (which packages them, unless I misread your post);
- Use setup.py clean build to remove artifacts from previous builds;
- (wild try) Use MANIFEST.in exclude patterns.

If these don’t work, can you say more about the sequence of commands that cause __pycache__ directories to be created and then installed?